# Retrieve 'name' from model.model.name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get the name value from the model `Organiser` through model `Event`.

My class `Organiser`:

```
class Organiser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :events
end
```

My model `Event`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :organiser
  has_many :subscribers
end
```

In Grails, that is a straightforward call:

```
def eventInstance = Event.find....

def organiserInstance = eventInstance.organiser
```

`organiserInstance.name` gave me the name from the organiser.

How is this done in Ruby on Rails? I tried:

```
@orgName = @eventInstance.organiser.name
```

but then I get an error:

```
undefined method `organiser' for #<Event::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f86152ef098>
```

Comment: Really, really shallow nitpick: Rails is all about convention over configuration, and it really packs a punch when you stick to its naming conventions (https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/f5d2be2ef3735889d315). You'll definitely avoid future, otherwise-avoidable headaches if you follow it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means your `@eventInstance` is in fact a collection, not a single instance.

You will want to first set `@eventInstance` to be a single instance of `Event` model. Then your code will work:

```
@eventInstance = Event.first
@orgName       = @eventInstance.organizer.name
```

P.S. Ruby convention is to call variables using snake case, not camel case:

```
@event_instance = Event.first
@org_name       = @event_instance.organizer.name
```

Comment: No it is not. It is a single instance...   @eventInstance = Event.where(eventcode: session[:key]) gave me a single record

Comment: @diedaaf it gives you a *collection* ***with*** a single record. you want to make it `Event.where(eventcode: session[:key]).first` to get single *record*.

Comment: Event.where(evencode: session[:key] gave me a single record cause there is only 1 event with that key

Comment: @diedaaf do you read what I write? [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) ***returns*** you a collection. Just do what I suggest and make sure it is what you need. I linked documentation, please read it through if you feel like it.

Comment: I stand corrected. the .first is the way to do it. That differs from Grails ;-) Thanks!!

Comment: @diedaaf I never coded anything in Grails thus didn't know :)

Comment: You can also use `Event.find_by(eventcode: ...)`, that returns a single instance.

Comment: @diedaaf yep, above shown `find_by` is one of the options to go with if you need single object with single query to DB. Make sure to accept the answer if it solves your problem and you do not expect new answers.